# How to white list root path with wildcard but not additional sub paths?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm not sure if the description is correct, but I have the following paths:

- `/feature_flags/{featureFlagName}`
- `/feature_flags/{featureFlagName}/business/{businessId}`

Is there a way to white list the first one but not any sub-paths:

- `/feature_flags/{featureFlagName}` -> allow this only
- `/feature_flags/{featureFlagName}/xx`  -> block all that have additional path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your security config add the path with only something like:

```
.antMatchers("/feature_flags/*").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/feature_flags/*/**").authenticated()
```

Or other rules (`hasRole`, `hasAuthority`) that you may need.